# Explain why vertical angles must be congruent

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I know why vertical angles are congruent but I dont know why they must be congruent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two intersecting lines form two pair of congruent vertical angles. If the vertical angles of two intersecting lines *fail to be congruent*, then the two intersecting "lines" must, in fact, *fail to be lines*...so the "vertical angles" would not, in fact, be "vertical angles", by definition.

Perhaps you'd be interested in viewing a proof of this at the Khan Academy video:

- See [**A proof that two vertical angles are congruent**](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/parallel-and-perpendicular-lines/ang_intro/v/proof-vertical-angles-are-equal).

Answer (score 3):

Recall that if $\angle BAC$ and $\angle BAD$ are supplementary angles, and if $\angle B'A'C'$ and $\angle B'A'D'$ are supplementary angles, and if $\angle BAC\cong\angle B'A'C'$, then also $\angle BAD\cong\angle B'A'D'$. (This is Proposition 9.2 on page 92 of Robin Hartshorne's *Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*.) A proof may be found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=EJCSL9S6la0C&pg=PA92&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Now vertical angles are defined by the opposite rays on the same two lines. Suppose $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ are vertical angles, hence each supplementary to an angle $\beta$. Since $\beta$ is congruent to itself, the above proposition shows that $\alpha\cong\alpha'$.

Answer (score 2):

When two straight lines intersect at a point, four angles are made. The non-adjacent angles are called vertical or opposite . Also, each pair of adjacent angles forms a straight line and the two angles are supplementary. Since either of a pair of vertical angles is supplementary to either of the adjacent angles, the vertical angles are equal in 
value or size.